Azure AI Search Index Returning Incorrect URLs and Keywords
I'm encountering an issue with Azure AI Search and could use some assistance.

Setup:

Extracted text from a website containing product information.
Stored the extracted content in JSON format on Azure AI Search Index:
[
  {
    "url": "https://hello-world.com/groups/products/product1",
    "content": {
      "text": "website content",
      "tables": [only if there are table contents]
    }
  }
]

Index Schema
"fields": [
    { "name": "key", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": false },
    { "name": "source_link", "type": "Edm.String","searchable": false, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false
    },
    { "name": "content","type": "Edm.String","searchable": true, "filterable": false,"sortable": false,"facetable": false
    },
    { "name": "keywords","type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": true,"filterable": true,"sortable": false,"facetable": true
    },
    { name="content_vector","type":"Collection(Edm.Single)", "retrievable":true,"searchable":true, vector_search_dimensions=1536, vector_search_profile_name="my-vector-config"},
    { name="keyword_vector","type":"Collection(Edm.Double)", "retrievable":true}
  ]


API Implementation:

Developed an API function web_search() for querying the Azure AI Search Index.
Combined citations from unstructured PDF data (which returns the answer, 3 documents, and product keywords) with results from web_search() (which returns URL and keywords if matched).

Problem:

The index fails to return the correct URL and keywords every time a question is asked.
The unstructured data API consistently returns correct results.
Question:
How can I resolve this issue to ensure the Azure AI Search Index consistently returns the correct URL and keywords when a question is asked?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

What question you asked? Please add those details with expected output.

Also please add you sample index definition.

@JayashankarGS, I've updated the above question by adding the index schema for your reference.

I've extracted the Text from a website which contains only product details & stored the extracted text into JSON. Loaded the JSON in Azure AI Search Index, written an API for web_search() which is being implemented with one of our unstructured_search() where it will return the url & keywords of the website along with metatdata of unstrucutred_search(). But the unstructured_search is returning the correct response where as web_search() is failing to retrieive the correct URL & keywords (as it is failing to identify the products).

Refer to this link for Issues with Azure AI Search Index Returning Incorrect URLs and Keywords

@Sampath, The link you shared refers to the indexers to check for any errors. But in our scenario we've written a python script where it uploads the document into the indexes.

Could please share the code in text format.
